# Foursquare nearest venue search sorting

Tags: search, location, foursquare

When I wanted to check in, I noticed that Swarm **doesn't sort venues based on distance alone**. Closer venues can (somehow) end up lower in the list. Yet my current venue mysteriously appears on the top even if it's not the closest one.

I'm currently implementing SQL-backed cache on top of the Foursquare API (so that I don't have to call the API too often) and need to replicate this behavior.

When I issue API `venue/search` request with `intent=checkin`, the correct venue pops out on top right away. But when I do a distance-sorted search in my database (with identical data), the outcome is imprecise and thus unacceptable.

Does anybody have any thoughts on this matter? What algorithm might Swarm be using to achieve this kind of precision given only a location and the accuracy of measurement?